# ffmpeg deocde without producing output file

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg to decode a h264 file.

Since I just want to measure the decoding time, the output file creation will spend a lot of time and time measurement will be not so accurate.

So could anyone help to solve this problem?

I use "ffmpeg -i  blue_sky.h264 output.yuv "to decode.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want measure only decoding time, I think you should use raw null format to /dev/null as output. You can do it with this command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f null /dev/null
```

Comment: I still has some small questions. If using the above command, what format on earth is the output file?  is it original yuv format?

Comment: There is no output with this filter settings, its just decoding. [http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#null] See documentation. As for color space, it should stay the same as input.

Comment: I just wanted to note something. In the ffmpeg docs you see places where it recommends to use `/dev/null` for Unix and `NUL` for Windows, which is technically correct, but even if you write a filename, it will not be written to (which is good to know since I don't need to check for Windows/Unix). I just leave it as `-` since it's visually consistent with other apps that use that as a "piped input/output indicator" but a name (like `null`) also works.